# How to prevent URL variables tampering in PHP?

Tags: php, web-applications, cakephp, security

I am building a web app in CakePHP, authorized users can add, update, delete a record. In some controllers to add a record my URLs structure is like:

```
records/add/id_of_parent_record/secondvar:another_decision_dependent_value.
```

My concern is a user may tamper with these GET variables which would result in corrupting the whole record. I know i can use sessions for these vars, but I am looking for the best approach. Please share you knowledge and experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the POST and Post/Redirect/Get advice.. In general:

Never ever trust any of the information you receive in a HTTP request (including GET parameters, POSTed data, Cookies and HTTP headers). Always ensure the user has permission to perform each action on the data objects in question and you always validate on the server side that the data is as sensible as you can, before accepting and processing it.

Comment: Well my point is Only authenticated users can access the action. And I am not trusting the user input as well. Now My the e.g. they access a category page and add another product in it the URL for that would be like add/cat_id/. Now still cat_id will be checked for validation etc. My concern is user could just change the URL to add/some_other_valid_cat_id. Should I send the cat_id set in session? Otherwise I have a check that the URL is coming from proper view.

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain why this is a bad thing in your application design. What is wrong with the user adding an item to some_other_valid_cat_id and why is that different to them adding an item to cat_id?

Comment: yes this is a valid point. Why is it bad? After all the user with all permissions is adding. But in my application If someone tries to alter the values and if it is not coming from a valid source, I redirect it.

Answer (score 3):

General rule of thumb is that URL variables (of any kind, so that includes everything in the URL) should only be used in selecting and displaying variables. This way, if the user screws up something, so what? They screwed up and you're not guaranteeing that support. They don't have easy ability to futz with backend data by pasting the wrong thing in (This is more or less the idea behind the RESTful GET).

If something needs to be modified, on the other hand, it should be done both with authentication (HTTP Authentication is considered more ideal) so that only users who have authority to modify *can* modify. It also is generally done through PUT/POST/DELETE request. In the PHP frameworks, POST would be the easiest/most common as PUT and DELETE take a good deal more effort for complete support in PHP.

Comment: Well my point is Only authenticated users can access the action. And I am not trusting the user input as well. Now My the e.g. they access a category page and add another product in it the URL for that would be like add/cat_id/. Now still cat_id will be checked for validation etc. My concern is user could just change the URL to add/some_other_valid_cat_id. Should I send the cat_id set in session? Otherwise I have a check that the URL is coming from proper view.

Answer (score 2):

Always use a POST request for this kind of stuff (Create, Update, Delete) , so it can't happen accidentally.
But even if you use POST, do not trust user input.

Also have a look at [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).